# Unrecognized iframe rendering in Wordpress markup

Tags: wordpress

I was inspecting browser elements on a Wordpress 3.4.1 site and came across an iframe I don't recognize.

```
<body class=" customize-support">

<iframe src="http://mickajoin.tumblr.com/?d=www.example.net" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" scrolling="no" width="0px" height="0px"></iframe>

<div id="wrapper">
  ...
```

Of course http://mickajoin.tumblr.com doesn't exist so this returns 404 anyway. Searching the project resulted in nothing. Google returned nothing relevant.

Initially I thought it was the Gallery plugin. I disabled it and the iframe persisted. I've also deactivated the other 2 third-party plugins use on the site. None of this worked.

I'm hoping someone can point to me the sources of where this could be injected.

Comment: I just recently had this problem myself. I found out that it was created by a chrome-extension. I deleted all my extensions and it dissapeared. Since i just deleted them all i dont know which one it was... But its gone now... Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip on the extension. Turns out it was Pokemon Tower Defense HD 5.6 for me. ^_^